# Accessing list from a different class

Tags: c#, list, api, xamarin

I need to access some data from a database using a REST API. This API call is made in a different class called `MobileAppController`.

Using another class called `MessageService` the data from the API call is being put into a List and is subsequently returned as: "Items".
 Now I have another class called `UserMessages.xaml.cs`, which is the backend of the page the user is going to see.

On this page I have a `ListView` in which all the data is going to be. My struggle now is trying to get the data from "Items" in my other List which is called "Messages".

For clarification, Items is in the `MessageService` class and Messages is in the `UserMessages.xaml.cs` class. So far what I have tried hasn't worked out.

**MessageService.cs class:**

```
public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private readonly IRestService _restService;

    public List<MessageViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public MessageService(IRestService service)
    {
        _restService = service;
    }

    public async Task<List<MessageViewModel>> GetMessages()
    {
        Items = new List<MessageViewModel>();

        Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MessageViewModel>>(await _restService.GetData("GetMessages", "state=0"));

        return Items;
    }
}
```

**UserMessage.xaml.cs class:**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class UserMessages : ContentPage
{
    List<ViewModels.MessageViewModel> Messages { get; set; }
    public UserMessages()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Messages = new List<Items>();
        MessageLV.ItemsSource = Messages;
    }

}
```

I have tried a few methods but non of them have worked out so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your MessageService a singleton and have an async method in your UserMessages class to initialise your Messages property from the GetMessages method.

```
public static MessageService Shared => instance.Value;
private static readonly Lazy<MessageService> instance =
            new Lazy<MessageService>(() => new MessageService());
```

And in the OnAppearing method of your UserMessages:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    try
    {
       Messages = await MessageService.Shared.GetMessages();
       MessageLV.ItemsSource = Messages;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

I would also suggest using dependency injection for your MessageService.

Answer (score 0):

page has an `OnAppearing` method you can use

```
public async override void OnAppearing()
{
    // svc is a instance of MessageService
    Messages = await svc.GetMessages();
    MessageLV.ItemsSource = Messages;
}
```